# pymongo fails to work with multithreading

Tags: python, multithreading, mongodb, pymongo

the following code does not work, either in python2.6 or python3.2.

Test Code:

```
import pymongo

class A(Thread):  
        def __init__(self):  
            Thread.__init__(self)  
            self.conn = pymongo.Connection('localhost',30000)  
            self.mongo = self.conn.puppet  
            self.mongo.authenticate('test','123')  
        def run(self):  
            print self.mongo.href.find_one()  

A().start()
```

Exception Message:

```
 OperationFailure: database error: unauthorized db:puppet lock
   type:-1 client:127.0.0.1
```

Any ideas how to fix this?

Comment: And of course, my mongodb is up and running.  I've tested it without multithreading and all works well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is probably due to how authentication is handled in pymongo, see the [note in the API docs](http://api.mongodb.org/python/current/api/pymongo/database.html#pymongo.database.Database.authenticate) - Pymongo doesn't cache authentication credentials between threads, so each thread must authenticate individually.

Comment: Yeah, "each thread must authenticate individually", that's what I did. And now I believe it's a bug that we cann't use authentication and multithreading at the same time.

Comment: I believe what my code complies to the Pymongo API - I am using  a distinct instance in my thread. and your advice doesn't really solve my problem. So sorry, I can't accept your answer even it's the only one.

Comment: Understood - which version of pymongo and mongoDB are you using? -  there have been some recent-ish improvements here in the 2.0 release: https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/PYTHON-4

Comment: I will try the new release later. Anyway this is a bug of pymongo, and thanks for your time.

Comment: This answer is incorrect as of pymongo 2.0+, as Adam C tried to point out.  http://api.mongodb.org/python/current/api/pymongo/database.html#pymongo.database.Database.authenticate says:  ``When sharing a Connection between multiple threads, all threads will share the authentication.``

Comment: That's why I get the same error with Rust driver. Thank you. Works ok when every thread authorized.